# vue.js components - pass default values from parent (across multiple instances)

Tags: vue.js, components

I am new to Vue.js and am trying to create components that will simplify form creation, based on a library I have been using for a while now (PHP).

I have created a component that renders a label + textbox, styled via Bootstrap.
In order to avoid having to pass all the parameters every time, I want to be able to define defaults from within the parent, so that they will stay in effect until changed.

The component looks like this (**MyTextBox.vue**)

```
<template>
<div v-bind:class="myDivWidth">
    <label v-bind:class="`control-label ${myLabelWidth}`">{{label}}</label>
    <div v-bind:class="myControlWidth">
        <input class="form-control col-md-12" v-bind:value="value">
   </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            // trying to use this as 'class' variable but most likely wrong
            myDefaultLabelWidth: 4
        }
    },
    props: {
        label: String,
        labelWidth: String,
        controlWidth: String,
        divWidth: String,
        value: {required: false},
        defaultLabelWidth: {type: String}
    },
    computed: {
        myLabelWidth: function () {
            let lw;
            //debugger;
            do {
                if (typeof this.defaultLabelWidth !== 'undefined') {
                    lw = this.defaultLabelWidth;
                    // ****** Note the call to the parent function
                    this.$parent.setDefault('defaultLabelWidth', lw);
                    break;
                }

                if (typeof this.labelWidth !== 'undefined') {
                    lw = this.labelWidth;
                    break;
                }

                if (typeof this.lw !== 'undefined') {
                    lw = this.lw;
                    break;
                }
                // ****** Note the call to the parent function
                lw = this.$parent.getDefault('defaultLabelWidth');
            } while (false);

            return `col-md-${lw}`;
        },
        // snip....
    }
}
</script>
```

and it is used like this (I am only showing attributes relating to label, for brevity)
**(StoryEditor.vue)**

```
<my-textbox label="LableText1" default-label-width=4></my-textbox>
<my-textbox label="LableText2"></my-textbox>
<my-textbox label="LableText3" label-width=5></my-textbox>
<my-textbox label="LableText4"></my-textbox>
<my-textbox label="LableText5" default-label-width=6></my-textbox>
<my-textbox label="LableText6"></my-textbox>
<my-textbox label="LableText7"></my-textbox>
```

What this is meant to do, is set the label with to 4, for the first 2 instances
then force a width of 5 for the next instance
then go back to 4
then set a new default of 6 for the remaining 3 components.

This is useful in cases where a lot of components (of the same type) are used, most of which are of the same width.
This mechanism will also used for all other applicable attributes.

Please note that what is important here is that the default is set in the parent and can change between instances of the component.
(I am aware that I can have a default value in the template itself but, as I understand it, that would apply to all instances of that component)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**[Edit]
I have found one solution:**
I added these methods to the parent **(StoryEditor.vue)**.
They are called by the component code, shown above with '******' in the comments

```
<script>
export default {
    created: function () {
        // make sure the variable exists
        if (typeof window.defaultOptions === 'undefined') {
            window.defaultOptions = {
                defaultLabelWidth: 3,
                defaultControlWidth: 7
            };
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            story: {
            }
        }
    },      
    methods: {
        getDefaultOptions: () => {
            console.log('getDefaultOptions', window.defaultOptions);
        },
        setDefaultOptions: (opts) => {
            window.defaultOptions = opts;
        },
        getDefault: (option) => {
            console.log('   getDefault', window.defaultOptions);
            return window.defaultOptions[option];
        },
        setDefault: (option, v) => {
            window.defaultOptions[option] = v;
            console.log('setDefault', window.defaultOptions);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

This uses **this.$parent.** to call methods in the parent.
The parent then uses a window variable to store/retrieve the relevant parameters.
A window variable is used because I want to have a **single** variable that will be used by all instances of the component.

Comment: I dont think so its possible in vue. The only best thing possible as per the design of props is that you can set the default value in the child component itself. And override it, if you need to, from parent.

Comment: Thanks @Deepak. I think I have found a way to achieve this. A rudimentary version of it is shown in the edited post above